# Making a list in LibreOffice Calc from other lists of unknown legnth

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have one worksheet (data) with the columns (maximum rows is 100):

```
  | A                     | B      | C        | D      | E        |
--|-----------------------|--------|----------|--------|----------|
1 | non_important_columns | time_a | reason_a | time_b | reason_b |
2 | ..................... | 00:13  | blam     | 00:59  | bang     |
3 | ..................... | 00:27  | bung     |        |          |
4 | ..................... | 01:14  | bint     | 02:31  | brik     |
```

From this data I want to make a report as a list:

```
  | A      | B     | C      |
--|--------|-------|--------|
1 | source | time  | reason |
2 | time_a | 00:13 | blam   |
3 | time_a | 00:27 | bung   |
4 | time_a | 01:14 | bint   |
5 | time_b | 00:59 | bang   |
6 | time_b | 02:31 | brik   |
```

I wont now before hand what cells actually have data in them, but I don't want any empty cells in the list. Ideally I would like to remove the 'source' column and instead color-code the results.

How could I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,

Kruffalon

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily copy the data from Calc to Base as described at https://superuser.com/a/1216718/541756.  Use the following query.

```
SELECT 'a' AS "source", "time_a", "reason_a" FROM "Table1" WHERE "time_a" <> ''
UNION
SELECT 'b' AS "source", "time_b", "reason_b" FROM "Table1" WHERE "time_b" <> ''
```

**Color coding**

After the results are in Calc, manually select the "a" rows and set them to a certain background color, and a different color for the "b" rows.  Then delete the source column.

**A suggestion**

Consider using Base with MySQL to maintain this data rather than Calc.  Without knowing more about this project, I cannot give advice as to which would be better.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Base, didn't know it existed, and I'm generally much more comfortable with DB:s than Spreadsheets.